# Testing input component with jest Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have a simple Input component which I want to test with jest, enzyme.

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import React from 'react';

const TextComponent = (props) => {
  const handleInputChange = (name) => ({ target }) => {
    props.handleChange({ [name]: target.value }, target.value);
  };
  return (
    <TextField onChange={handleInputChange(props.name)} {...props} className="textComponent" />
  );
};

export default TextComponent;
```

My test case look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { TextComponent } from '../../../tests';

test('<TextComponent> with label, name', () => {
  const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
  const handleChangeMock = jest.fn();
  const input = mount(
    <TextComponent
      label="Test"
      onChange={onChangeMock}
      value="test value"
      variant="outlined"
      name="testname"
      handleChange={handleChangeMock}
    />
  );
  expect(input.props().label).toEqual('Test');
  expect(input.props().name).toEqual('testname');
  expect(input.props().variant).toEqual('outlined');
  input.find('input').simulate('change');
  expect(handleChangeMock).toBeCalledWith({testname: 'test value'}, 'test value');
});
```

While running the test case I am getting an error saying

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `handleChange` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it
 as lowercase `handlechange` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

How can I test if my handleChangeMock function is being invoked with the correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tests, these props are passed to `TextComponent`

```
//...
      label="Test"
      onChange={onChangeMock}
      value="test value"
      variant="outlined"
      name="testname"
      handleChange={handleChangeMock}
//...
```

However in `TextComponent` implementation all these props are forwarded in `MUITextField` after decorating `handleChange` prop.

```
<TextField onChange={handleInputChange(props.name)} {...props} className="textComponent" />
```

The `handleChange` prop needs to be left out from being forwarded in `MUITextField` component after it's decorated and passed as `onChange` prop for `MUITextField` component.

This can be accomplished using object de-structuring.

```
const TextComponent = (props) => {
  const {handleChange, ...restProps} = props;
  const handleInputChange = (name) => ({ target }) => {
    handleChange({ [name]: target.value }, target.value);
  };
  return (
    <TextField
        onChange={handleInputChange(props.name)} 
        {...restProps} 
        className="textComponent"
    />
  );
};
```

Also, leave out `onChange` prop in the test. It is overriding the decorated `onChange` prop in `TextComponent` implementation because `restProps` will contain another `onChange` prop.